# VPS not replying on ftp port 21 using pure-ftpd

Tags: ftp, pure-ftpd

There is no response from my VPS when I connect to the ftp service on port 21. It's a Linux server with kloxo and pure-ftp. I have been using it without troubles from past 8 months. I installed ConfigServer before few months, which didn't create any troubles but to check, I have disabled it.

It starts working at sometime for few minutes and then again stops for like 2-3hours and then again work for like 10-20minutes.

I tried connecting using telnet and it was blank response but after a few minutes, it started working.

Comment: And yes, I can connect to the vps, from the browser, login to the control panel etc. all working only ftp is a trouble.

Comment: Disable any/all firewalls and try again. Check your system logs for restarts/crashes. Your question is far too vague, please look into the problem more and update the Question.

Comment: Thanks for the migration Chris S. I have had only one firewall ConfigServer, which I had disabled yesterday in an effort to resolve this problem, but didn't help.

Comment: checking server log to get more info.

Comment: Now is has permanently stopped. ConfigServer is turned off. Nothing in the server logs.